# Read data from the Word document in .docx format as each field and save it in database in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

Is it able to read data from .docx file as a field so that it was able to save in database? It is required to use Java.
As an example we have Word forms document like CV and we should read each field e.g.(Name, Surname, Age, Position, Date) so that it was able to save it in database not in one big text column, but as a separate field.
[image]
There 2 libraries exist in Java one of them is Apache POI the other one is docx4j but it gives an approach to save data in one big piece in one text field in the database.
But it should separate each field as an element.

I have done so that data is saved in one big piece.
As the result data is saved just only in this way
[image]

I haven't found any approach to to so.
Could you suggest something, please.

Comment: I am imaging you have specific delimiters (such as the bold colons next to the bolded field titles in the example image) in the Word file that separate which fields should be split into table rows. If so, what was your issue with POI for parsing the text out of the file and then Java's Scanner for parsing the text?

Comment: The text was successfully parsed but it is saved in one big piece as you can see on picture but I need so that each delimiter be parsed as a unique field and saved in database in each row.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. You can split by any delimiter or multiple delimiters using Scanner and regex, so the fact that you are getting a single String from POI seems unimportant if you take that string and then parse it as you would if you were using a text file... I don't have access to Word for the next few hours, but I'll provide an example when I can...at least unless you tell me what I am proposing is not what you are trying to do

Comment: But it is required to parse .docx file.

Comment: This didn't even require a Scanner, the POI library is pretty simple. Check my answer, it should do what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse a Microsoft Word Document with the input example you provided and grab specific values for each line.

First, here is the format of the test file I used, I placed it in my local directory and it follows the same format of your example image:

> **Employee**
>
> **Name:** Bob
>
> **Surname:** Smith
>
> **Age:** 28
>
> **Position:** Developer
>
> **Date:** 6/26/18

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;

    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //exampleFile is the layout file you provided with data added for testing
        List<String> values = parseWordDocument("exampleFile.docx");
        
        for(String s: values)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
    
    public static List<String> parseWordDocument(String documentPath) {
        FileInputStream fInput = null;
        XWPFDocument document = null;
        List<String> parsedValues = null;
        
        try {
            File file = new File(documentPath);
            
            fInput = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            document = new XWPFDocument(fInput);
            
            //getParagraphs() will grab each paragraph for you
            List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();

            parsedValues = new LinkedList<>();
           
            for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {
                //remove the title
                if(!para.getText().equals("Employee")) {
                    //here is where you want to parse your line to get needed values
                    String[] splitLine = para.getText().split(":");
                    //based on example input file [1] is the value you need
                    parsedValues.add(splitLine[1]);
                }
            }
            
            fInput.close();
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return parsedValues;
    }

}
```

With this, the output I get from the List created by **parseWordDocument()** is:

> Bob
>
> Smith
>
> 28
>
> Developer
>
> 6/26/18

So now you can simply take the returned list and loop that (instead of printing out the values) and create the appropriate SQLite query.

Comment: Thank you so much for this example!

Comment: No worries, glad it helped!